# Spring jdbc template how to decrypt password?

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, password-encryption

Here is my configuration file which i use to create DAO object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXX:XXX"/>
   <property name="username" value="encryptedUsername"/>
   <property name="password" value="decrytedPassword"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fiBillJDBCTemplate" class="com.tfl.fi.billing.dao.FIBillingDAOImpl">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Normally we can create database object as follows

```
   ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Parent.xml");
       FIBillingDAOImpl dao = 
          (FIBillingDAOImpl)context.getBean("fiBillJDBCTemplate");
```

But this wont work as the password stored in xml file is encrypted.

How can an DAO object be made in such a way that password will be decrypted.

Comment: Both username and password are encrypted or only password in conf.xml?

Comment: both username and password are decrypted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend `DriverManagerDataSource` to handle the decryption logic. You need to add the logic to decode password and return it from `decode` method E.g.

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EncryptedDriverManagerDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource {

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        String password = super.getPassword();
        return decode(password);
    }

    /**
     * You can implement you own decoding method.
     */
    private String decode(String decode) {
        //HERE
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that in your spring configuration file use this class as datasource

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="EncryptedDriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXX:XXX"/>
    <property name="username" value="foo"/>
    <property name="password" value="encryptedPassword"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Class you use here (`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`) can't be changed.

I suggest you either :

1. Override this class, and override the setPassword method in order to decrypt the password value.
2. Use a custom Property placeholder that does encryption (something like [this](http://kayalvizhiameen.blogspot.in/2014/04/handling-obfuscated-property-values-in.html))